# Sequence of Constant Diagonal Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, functional-analysis

Suppose that a sequence of matrices $\{B_k\}$ in $M_n (\Bbb{C})$ converges to $B$ in some norm topology on $M_n(\Bbb{C})$ (it doesn't matter which norm you consider since we are working in a finite dimensional space), where the diagonal of $B_k$ is the identity matrix. Does this imply that $B$'s diagonal is the identity matrix?

Here's one strategy. Since $M_n(\Bbb{C})$ under the norm topology is Hausdorff, in which convergent sequences have unique limits, then if I can show that $B_k$ converges to $C := B_0 + I$ also, where $B_0$ is formed by replacing $B$'s diagonal with zeros, then it follows that $B=C$. If I could show that $\| B_{k,0} - B_0 \| \le \|B_k - B \|$, then I would be done. But I can't see it at the moment; it's probably trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T_{ij} : M_n(\mathbb C) \to \mathbb C$ be given by $T_{ij}(A) = A_{ij}$. Then $T_{ij}$ is linear and thus is continuous. So if $B_k$ converges to $B$, then

$$B_{ij} = T_{ij} (B) = T_{ij} \left( \lim_{k\to\infty} B_k\right) = \lim_{k\to\infty} T_{ij} (B_k) = \lim_{k\to\infty} 0 = 0.$$